# Can't use a public static method?

Tags: java, android

This is confusing. I'm look at the [Android 2.2.2_r1 source code for the NotificationManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.2_r1/android/app/NotificationManager.java/) class, and I see the method `getService()` which is defined as `public` and `static`. However, eclipse is telling me:

> The method getService() is undefined for the type NotificationManager
>   on the line

```
 Object o = NotificationManager.getService();
```

My project is building against Android 2.2/ API Level 8. I tried to use reflection to see the method names and modifiers, and sure enough, I got back

`public static getService`

Am I missing something here? Why would eclipse tell me this method doesn't exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find a very detailed answer in [this post](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/).

In short: Because you compile against the `android.jar`, which has all hidden methods (like the one you are trying to access) removed. They will only be there on runtime, for internal android usage.

---

But since you perhaps also need it. The right way to access the `NotificationManager` is via the [`getSystemService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) method of a context:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

With `context` being a valid context (like your current activity).

Comment: That's funny, I was reading that post, came back and found that you had posted it as an answer. I actually am trying to find a hack that would allow me to get a list of notifications, so the normal way of getting the notification manager isn't what I need.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand exactly why the normal way doesn't work for you? The `NotificationManager` returned by this method is the same like the one returned by `getService`.

Comment: @you786 - spontaneously I'd say that you can't find a list that way - at least not through the `INotificationManager` API which is what the `NotificationManager` uses internally to talk to the `NotificationManagerService`.

Comment: @Jens Hmm.. so is there any way I could get a hold of the NotificationManagerService object directly?

Comment: As an installable app on a non-custom ROM I'd guess no.